# Correct way of asking a question in the past tense - "How many pegs...?"

Tags: past-tense, questions, british-english

Which sentence construction is correct?

> How many pegs **did you have**?
>
> How many pegs **did you drink**?
>
> How many pegs **you drank**?
>
> How many pegs **have you drank**?
>
> How many pegs **you have had**?

I am confused about this sentence **How many pegs you drank?** is this correct English

Or is there any other better way asks someone?

Answer (score 2):

In general, questions in English must include one of the following:

- a helping (auxiliary) verb, such as have, will, and would,
- a form of the verb *be*,
- or a form of the verb *do* as an auxiliary verb, if neither of the above is present. In this case, the main verb is not modified by the subject or tense. "Does she drive?" is correct, while "Does she drives?" is not. "Did she drive?" is correct, not "Did she drove?"

In any past tense, the helping verbs are simply conjugated in the tense desired, such as *did, were, was, had*, etc.

Let's apply these rules to your examples.

> How many pegs **did you have**?

This is correct, because it includes the helping verb *do* in past tense.

> How many pegs **did you drink**?

Also correct, for the same reason as above.

> How many pegs **you drank**?

This is incorrect; it does not have either a helping verb, a form of *be*, or a form of *do*. It is actually corrected by the sentence below it.

> How many pegs **have you drank**?

This is correct, since the helping verb *have* is present, and drink is correctly put into the past participle form *drank*. This is how the sentence above it should read.

> How many pegs **you have had**?

This is close, but the subject and verb should be inverted to form "How many pegs **have you** had?"

Answer (score 0):

Of the three options, the top one would be the best.

Assuming that you are asking a question regarding how many alcoholic drinks someone has had, you might want to go for 'How many drinks did you have?' or: 'could you walk this straight line please'

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have edited my question. I am confused about this sentence **How many pegs you drank?** is this correct English

Comment: no, although it could be correct if used as the end of a sentence. For instance: 'do you remember how many pegs you drank?'

Answer (score -1):

**How many drinks have you had?** would be the correct way of asking this question.

Comment: One needs context to decide between Past Indefinite and Present Perfect.  "How many drinks did you have?" is just as correct.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have edited my question. I am confused about this sentence **How many pegs you drank?** is this correct English

Answer (score -2):

You can make indirect questions such as

> I'd like to know how many pegs you have had?
>
> I wonder how many pegs you drank?